# cannot execute docker container making error that OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused

Tags: linux, docker

I tried executing docker container but cannot execute.
Error message below.

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:101: executing setns process caused \"exit status 1\"": unknown
```

I don't find out exact reason of this error.

The container is up by docker-compose and I tried stopping or restarting this container but it doesn't work.

Any idea on this error, leave comment please.

Comment: Some more info would certainly help to help with that. I.e. what command are you running (I assume `docker exec`, but what more, which arguments, ...) and what image the container is running. If the image is not publically available maybe you could share the Dockerfile?